# dataframe: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I am not sure why I am getting this strange error for this simple if condition.
I have added the function `funt` to check values in each row of column 'Owner',
first I am checking if row in column 'Owner has any of these values `[ 'hal','jula','huli']`, if yes then it should return `'cont'`.
This returned value will be used to create new column(team) in dataframe `df`.
Whenever I try to run below code I get this error.

```
def funt(row):
  if df['Owner'] in ['hal','jula','huli']:   # error line
     return 'cont'
  elif df['Owner'] == "assigned":
     return "unassigned"
  elif df['Owner'] == "Other":
     return "Other"
  else:
     return "Something else"

df['team'] = df.apply(lambda row: funt(row), axis=1)
```

Error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Nobody can see what you did there. Make your code clear to follow it, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: What is `df['Owner'] in ['hal','jula','huli']` supposed to do...? That line makes no sense, so I don't think it's such a bad thing that there's an exception. EDIT: Are you trying to check if one of the owners is hal, jula, or huli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, I'm assuming you want to check the value of the row item "Owner" against the list in your if statement?  Would you not instead want to write

`if row['Owner'] in ['hal', 'jula', 'huli']:`

as it looks that the row object is being passed into the function? df['Owner'] on the other hand would attempt to check the entire dataframe Owner column against the list, therefore resulting in multiple True/False possibilities.  Hence, "ambiguous".

Alternatively, instead of using a function like that in the first place, you could do something like this:

```
mappings = {"assigned": "unassigned", "other": "Other"}
df.loc[:, 'Columns1'] = [mappings[value.lower()] if value.lower() in ["assigned", "other"] else "Something else" for value in df.loc[:, 'Owner']]
```